# Add tag (transformerless-deathtrap)?

Tags: discussion

Should we add a tag (transformerless-death-trap) for questions about transformerless AC mains power supplies, and all the reasons why that is almost always bad practice? Or at least a canonical question?

Inspired by this recent question 
[Transformerless AC-AC converter](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/324326/transformerless-ac-ac-converter)
Note the fritzing-style arduino and the two non-isolated AC mains sources conneted in series.

This general transformerless power supply idea is kind of an attractive nuisance. From a beginner's perspective, transformers are big and costly and heavy and scary, so why use them?

And under some conditions, it can make sense to use a properly-designed transformerless power supply. But often the issue of cost and (perceived) complexity makes beginners overestimate the value and underestimate the hidden costs of this approach. Lack of isolation is a big problem. If the entire load circuit is completely isolated from any human contact, then lack of primary isolation may be ok. But if it were my project, I'd be concerned that I might forget that the seemingly low-voltage stuff is actually "hot", so I'd just use a transformer.

But the hazards of working on AC mains power are not obvious. AC mains power can kill, under some conditions. Using a consumer-grade AC to DC "wall transformer" eliminates those conditions.

There have been past meta discussions about whether to answer questions about doing dangerous things. But my concern here is providing an easy-to-find reference point, about the technical issues surrounding correct transformerless power supply design, and the hazards that may not be so obvious.

Ok, I now see there's alreay an existing tag https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transformerless -- can we improve upon that somehow?

Comment: Not sure if you're mocking the person who asked the question or if you're actually serious LOL :)

Comment: Not mocking, I can see where they're coming from. I've unleashed my share of sparks, luckily my first arc welding experience didn't burn down my parents house.

Answer (score 6):

No, although I see the humor in your tag, tags are for:

1) [Searching questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/interesting-topics) that are similar in topic
2) Grouping questions under one topic

Adding a tag like this is not going to help users do either of these.

Furthermore here is [more info on tagging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/tagging):

> As a general rule, you should avoid creating new tags if possible, and
>   new users are not allowed to create new tags. Even if you have
>   sufficient reputation, you should only create new tags when you feel
>   you can make a strong case that your question covers a new topic that
>   nobody else has asked about before on this site.

Since the probability is high that you can't a make a strong case for adding this tag, and it won't be used. I would say don't add something that will be erased later and won't be used by other people.

Comment: Fair enough; like much of the stuff on meta it needed to be said more than it needed to be done...